# Facade Design Patterns and Subclassing

Tags: c#, subclass, facade

I am using a facade design pattern for a C# program. The program basically 
looks like this...

```
 public class Api
    {
        #region Constants

        private const int version = 1;

        #endregion


        #region Private Data

        private XProfile _profile;
        private XMembership _membership;
        private XRoles _role;

        #endregion Private Data


        public Api()
        {
            _membership =  new XMembership(); 
            _profile = new XProfile();
            _role = new XRoles();

        }

       public int GetUserId(string name)
       {
            return _membership.GetIdByName(name);
       }


}
```

Now, as I would like subclass my methods into three categories: Role, Profile, and Member. 
This will be easier on the developers eye because both Profile and Membership expose a lot of methods that look similar (and a few by Role). For example, getting a user's ID would look like:

```
int _id = Namespace.Api.Member.GetUserId("Henry222");
```

Can somebody "illustrate" how subclassing should work in this case to achieve the effect I am looking for?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would argue that you might mean "inner class" from the context of your question.  You might try something like the following...

```
public class Api
{
    public class MemberApi
    {
      private readonly Api _parent;

      internal MemberApi(Api parent) { _parent = parent; }

      public int GetUserId(string name)
      {
         return _parent._membership.GetIdByName(name);
      }
    }

    #region Constants

    private const int version = 1;

    #endregion


    #region Private Data

    private XProfile _profile;
    private XMembership _membership;
    private XRoles _role;

    public MemberApi { get; private set; }

    #endregion Private Data

    public Api()
    {
        _membership =  new XMembership(); 
        _profile = new XProfile();
        _role = new XRoles();

        Member = new MemberApi(this);
    }
}
```